# IELTS Listening Complaint due to coughing

Tags: ielts

I took the IELTS today and during the listening section and at the end during the last passage a student started constantly coughing. This made us lose track and miss the last part.

The center was playing the cd on a small portable cd player. When we went to complain the management of the center was shady and gave us 4 different explanations on what would happen if we decided to file written complaint each one nastier than before.

The last explanation they gave is that if IELTS investigates this and finds you are at fault then they will cancel this test and not give you a retest or refund. Hence we will lose out $300 and not get a test score.

I am not sure if this is true and was wondering if anyone can verify this.

(I am adding this last line because this question got put on hold for some reason of it being too general. I think that's invalid and this will prove very resourceful to everyone who takes this exam. So I am stating the country where this occurs making it general)

Please see this applies to all IELTS exam taken in USA where it's not standardized. It may apply to other countries as well where the exam is not standardized yet.

Comment: More likely they will make the test centre replace the test at their own expense...

Answer (score 5):

So I tried getting this resolved but was not successful. The center is responsible for the actions that need to be taken and IELTS (British Council I believe) will not participate in the process. The center decided that my inquiry was not valid and released my results. This obviously makes no sense to me. Also, I was told that it was my fault that I chose a center which did not have headphones so I have to bear the consequences according to IELTS. I hope this helps someone in the future pick a better center with headphones or a decent speaker system for listening.